# Verticies Error Using pgr_pointsaspolygon

Tags: pgrouting, vertices

I am doing the service areas analysis of hospitals. 
With the creation of areas I bumped into a problem with the pgr_pointsaspolygon function.

it returns the error:

```
ERROR:  Less than 3 vertices. Alpha shape calculation needs at least 3 vertices.

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function pgr_pointsaspolygon(character varying,double precision) 
line 17 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
```

11 service areas of 60x60 (1hr) only contain 2 vertices, this is cause for the whole function not to work.

How can I solve this? Can the function be edited? are there alternatives?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you are asking about -- you cannot create a polygon with only two verticies, that would just be a line. A service area would need to be a polygon, so I'm confused on what you are using as input data?

Answer (score 1):

If the input of the `pgr_pointsaspolygon` function receives less than three vertices, it's not possible to create a polygon.

If you run the request for multiple areas (11?), you need to first filter out those, that do not have enough vertices for a valid polygon.

The `pgr_pointsaspolygon` function doesn't do more than that, so it's not clear to me, what you mean with "cause for the the whole function not to work".

Comment: I'm using 619 hospitals for whole of Malawi (OSM all roads combined) imported using OSM2pgrouting. 

I've created a driving distance table with 60 minutes included for each hospital.

With the following code I am trying to create the service areas for each hospital:

Comment: create table hosp_area as
SELECT h.objectid, h.name, h.geom AS h_geom, v.the_geom As v_geom,
ST_SetSRID(pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
'SELECT seq As id, ST_X(geom) AS x, ST_Y(geom) As y
FROM dd_dc_hospitals10
WHERE from_v = ' || v.id::text ) ,4326) As geom
FROM dc_hospitals_10 AS h
,LATERAL (SELECT id, the_geom FROM ways_vertices_pgr AS n
ORDER BY h.geom <-> n.the_geom LIMIT 1) AS v;
Even after deleting all with less than 3 vertices I get the same error.